# libssl.a inside Custom iOS SDK Library causing duplicate symbols/definitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

My SDK uses a libssl.a library, but when I give it to a customer to use my SDK, they also uses a version of libssl.a and is causing duplicate symbol.   Is there anyway to allow both to coexist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to rebuild libssl with a custom prefix on each symbol. I wrote a script for this purpose, which you can find [here](https://github.com/chrisdevereux/nstool/blob/master/nstool.rb).

A simpler option might be to not link to libssl.a and require the customer to link to it instead. To do this, simply `#import` libssl's headers as usual, but leave libssl.a out from the link binary with libraries phase. The linker does not attempt to resolve symbols unless the target is an executable, so you will be able to compile a static library on this way without issues.

Comment: How would I not link the library during compiling of my SDK?  What would be the flags?

Comment: Basically you are saying I should compile with the libssl.a but not link it, I'm not sure how that will work.